# Does the rule $E(a+bg(X)+ch(X)) = a+bE(g(X))+cE(h(X))$ apply to any functions $g$ and $h$?

Tags: probability, statistics

I don't know why I am tend to think this way, but it always bothered me when my professor for mathematical statistics course apply the rule $E(a+bg(X)+ch(X)) = a+bE(g(X))+cE(h(X))$ to solve example problems without first checking that $g$ and $f$ are integrable function.

Because strictly speaking, the rule is proven by doing:

$E(a+bg(X)+ch(X))$
$ = \int_{x}(a+bg(x)+ch(x))f_X(x)dx $
$= \int_{x}af_X(x)dx + \int_{x}bg(x)f_X(x)dx + \int_{x}ch(x)f_X(x)dx$

$= a+ bE(g(x))+cE(h(x))$,

But to move from $\int_{x}(a+bg(x)+ch(x))f_X(x)dx $

to $\int_{x}af_X(x)dx + \int_{x}bg(x)f_X(x)dx + \int_{x}ch(x)f_X(x)dx$,

we first need to assume that the functions $bg(x)f_X(x)$ and $ch(x)f_X(x)$ are integrable.

Don't we first need to check whether $bg(x)f_X(x)$ and $ch(x)f_X(x)$ are integrable before we apply the rule?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're absolutely right.

As a trivial example, imagine that $X$ is a random variable with undefined expectation (say a Cauchy RV) and consider $E(1+X-X).$